# Javascript. How to use original JSON object (that was redefined by another developer)

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JS code like:

```
JSON.stringify({'a':'b'});
```

that works ok when is run standalone on my webpage. But when my code is put inside the production environment, some extra javascript files ruin my code totally. One of those extra js files has JSON object redefinition. And now my code is using this version of JSON object I don't want to use.

How can I tell javascript to use a built-in JSON object, not a custom one?

Some clarification:
This JSON object redefinition is done inside core javascript production libraries (my code is inserted inside old CMS). It looks like core developer wanted to create his own polyfill for old browsers. I am afraid to change his code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you mean they replaced the `JSON` class with a different one? Why?? You need to understand the purpose of that code and whether it's actually needed. Sounds like a pretty unprofessional effort, if it overrides built-in, basic functionality.

Comment: If at all possible, try to get rid of that extra js file... External script that redefine native functionality are basically dangerous.

Comment: How are these things defined? You might be able to `Object.freeze` them, but this might cause the other code to error.

Comment: Sounds like it's been [refuctured](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)

Comment: @Liam - is that some JS2021 thing? I haven't heard of that. They're always coming up with great things at Eczema International

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the old trick with an iframe to restore the global object:

```js
// some other code breaks global JSON
window.JSON = {
  stringify() { return "it's broken"; },
  parse()     { return "it's broken"; }
}

const obj = {foo: 1};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // it's broken

//later your code runs
(function() {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  const origJSON = iframe.contentWindow.JSON;
  document.body.removeChild(iframe);

  const json = origJSON.stringify(obj);
  
  console.log(json); // '{"foo":1}'
  console.log(origJSON.parse(json)); // { foo: 1 }
  
  //restore the global JSON
  window.JSON = origJSON;
})();

//afterwards global JSON works
const json = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(json); // '{"foo":1}'
console.log(JSON.parse(json)); // { foo: 1 }
```

However, this is ***not*** a reliable way to deal with these issue. It should only serve as a temporary workaround. In general, if your environment is broken due to some script outside of your control, you cannot guarantee the environment works correctly as long as the script is there.

Here is a simple example: let us say that script **A.js** breaks the global `JSON` object. Your script is **C.js** where you *do* restore `JSON` with your code. However, **B.js** runs after **A.js** and before **C.js** and tries to use `JSON`. It gets a wrong value and continues to use it. However, will not function correctly. Your environment is now still broken even after you fixed it.

It is an *exceptionally bad idea* to tamper with global objects. If any script does that, you are better off trying to replace it or fix it than continue to use it.

Answer (score 2):

By far, your best bet is to **not** include the file that redefines `JSON`, because `JSON` is defined in a particular way by the specification and shouldn't be overridden by something doing something different. **Lots** of things may well break (not just your code).

If you can't do that, you have a couple of choices:

1. Make sure your script is first and create a local variable private to your script and assign `JSON` to it, then use that local. You can even make the local `JSON`, like this:

   ```
   ;((JSON) => {
        // ...your code here...
   ))(JSON);
   ```
2. If your script has to be after the other one, then put a new script before it that saves the original `JSON`:

   ```
   const originalJSON = JSON;
   ```

   Then, again, use that in your code, perhaps like this:

   ```
   ;((JSON) => {
        // ...your code here...
   ))(originalJSON);
   ```

Comment: Oh my god, this core javascript library (with custom JSON object) is inserted first :(